# Unexpected result when using quantile in Julia vs Python

Tags: statistics, julia, quantile

I've just started with Julia and I am trying to do some simple statistics.

I'm using the StatsBase package and am trying to calculate quantiles.

```
using StatsBase

lst = 1:10

print(nquantile(lst, 4))
```

and get

```
[1.0, 3.25, 5.5, 7.75, 10.0]
```

Where I assume Q_1 = 3.25 and Q_2 = 7.75

Running a similar code on python:

```
from statistics import quantiles

lst = [_ for _ in range(1, 11)]
print(quantiles(lst))
```

yields:

```
[2.75, 5.5, 8.25]
```

Where Q_1 = 2.75 and Q_3 = 8.25.

According to my understanding of statistics, pythons results correspond to what the *actual* math is.

So, What I am guessing is that the Julia variant is using some kind of gaussian distribution to find the quantiles. If so, is there a way to make this follow uniform distribution?

Comment: There are many ways to calculate quantiles. Your guess about underlying distributions is wrong. Have you looked at the help pages? https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Statistics/ Wikipedia also provides [a helpful table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) (linked on the Julia help page).

Comment: (The Python `statistics` package offers 2 methods with a pretty reductive explanation in the docs. Julia and R offer more options and nicer references. If you don't feel like reading the paper cited in the Julia and R docs, I'd recommend the wikipedia link above and maybe the [R documentation link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile) to better understand what's going on. More options are also available in [numpy.quantile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html).)

Comment: `numpy`, Julia, and R all have the same default which is referred to a "linear" in the `numpy` docs. The `statistics.quantiles` function is labeled as "Weibull" in the `numpy` docs.

Comment: Oops, I see now I was using the `Statistics.quantile` Julia function, not your `StatsBase.nquantile`, which doesn't seem to have the method options. I'd suggest using `Statistics.quantile` directly.

Answer (score 4):

There are many quantile definitions and Julia implements all options found in *Hyndman, R.J and Fan, Y. (1996) Sample Quantiles in Statistical Packages", The American Statistician, Vol. 50, No. 4, pp. 361-365*

In order to get the Python equivalent do:

```
julia> quantile(1:10, (0:4)/4; alpha=0,beta=0)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.0
  2.75
  5.5
  8.25
 10.0
```

Explanation (found in docs):

```
help?> nquantile
(...)
  Equivalent to quantile(x, [0:n]/n). 
(...)
```

```
help?> quantile

  quantile(itr, p; sorted=false, alpha::Real=1.0, beta::Real=alpha)
(...)
  By default (alpha = beta = 1), quantiles are computed via linear interpolation between the points ((k-1)/(n-1),
  v[k]), for k = 1:n where n = length(itr). This corresponds to Definition 7 of Hyndman and Fan (1996), and is the  same as the R and NumPy default.

(...)
    •  Def. 6: alpha=0, beta=0 (Excel PERCENTILE.EXC, Python default, Stata altdef)
(...)
```